# Elementary countable submodels in Gödel's universe

Tags: set-theory, model-theory, ordinal-numbers, constructibility

By the downward Lowenheim-Skölem theorem we can find two countable ordinals $\alpha < \beta$ such that $L_\alpha \prec L_{\omega_1}$ and $L_\beta \prec L_{\omega_1}$. That is, $L_\alpha$ and $L_\beta$ are elementary submodels of $L_{\omega_1}$. Consequently, $L_\alpha \prec L_\beta$.

Hence my question, the other way around:

> Given countable ordinals $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $L_\alpha \prec L_\beta$, do we always have $L_\alpha \prec L_{\omega_1}$ ? If not, how do construct/prove the existence of such a $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Very clearly not. Take some countable elementary submodel $M_0$ of $L_{\omega_2}$, and take $M_1$ to be another one, but with $M_1$ a end extension of $M_0$. We can find such models by first finding two uncountable $\gamma<\delta$ such that $L_\gamma\prec L_\delta\prec L_{\omega_2}$, and then taking $M_1$ be a countable elementary submodel of $L_\delta$ with $L_\gamma$ added as a predicate to the language, and then letting $M_0$ be $M_1\cap L_\gamma$.

Now, since both are well-founded models of enough set theory and $V=L$, their transitive collapses are some $L_\alpha$ and $L_\beta$ which are countable, and the collapses agree on $M_0$.

Consequently we have that $L_\alpha\prec L_\beta$. But it is also clear that $L_\alpha$ (and $L_\beta$) think that they have an uncountable ordinal, whereas $L_{\omega_1}$ thinks that all the ordinals are countable.

Comment: Since $M_1$ has $M_0$ as an element and knows that it isn't transitive, it will have new elements witnessing that, and so the Mostowski collapse of $M_1$ won't agree with the collapse of $M_0$. So you'll only get an elementary embedding $L_\alpha\to L_\beta$, not elementary substructure. Right? For example, the order type of $M_0$ will be a new countable ordinal in $M_1$ but not in $M_0$, and this is less than $\omega_1^L\in M_0$.

Comment: To make an argument like this work, you need to find $M_0\prec M_1\prec L_{\omega_2}$ with $M_1$ being an end extension of $M_0$.

Comment: Ugh. That was my first instinct, but I hedged and changed it to the one written now. I'll edit it later when I'm back with a keyboard.

Comment: You can find end-extension models as needed by first taking an uncountable $\alpha$ with $L_\alpha\prec L_\beta\prec L_{\omega_2}$, and then taking a countable elementary substructure $M_1$ of $\langle L_\beta,\in,L_\alpha\rangle$, letting $M_0$ be the part of $M_1$ below $\alpha$. These will now collapse as desired.

Comment: Thanks, Joel. I've edited.

Answer (score 8):

No, there are many instances of $L_\alpha\prec L_\beta$ without $L_\alpha\prec L_{\omega_1}$.

Here is one easy way to construct one.
Consider the smallest $\alpha$ that has an elementary extension $L_\alpha\prec L_\beta$. There is indeed such a countable ordinal $\alpha$ as you observed, and this is visible inside $L_{\omega_1}$. So if $L_\alpha\prec L_{\omega_1}$, then there would have to be one below $\alpha$, contradicting minimality.

Comment: 12 seconds. Usain bolt ran a 100 meter dash between our answers, and had time to catch his breath afterwards, too!

Comment: Yes, indeed, you beat me by at least 150 meters! But we have different methods, so it is interesting...

Comment: Yes, I was glad to see that we took fairly different approaches.

Comment: Thank you for those quick answers! I guess those 12 seconds mean that I'll accept Karagila's answer.

Answer (score 8):

As Asaf and Joel have observed, the answer to your question is negative. However, there is a sense in which being an elementary submodel of $L_{\omega_1}$ is the only way to "persistently" get elementary submodelhood relations.

Specifically, the following are equivalent:

1. $L_\alpha\prec L_{\omega_1}$.
2. There is a club $S\subseteq\omega_1$ such that $L_\alpha\prec L_\beta$ for all $\beta\in S$.

---

But on the *other* other hand, if $V=L$ then there **is** an unbounded $U\subseteq \omega_1$ such that for all $\alpha,\beta\in U$ we have $L_\alpha\equiv L_\beta\not\equiv L_{\omega_1}$ *(note that this can't be proved using just a counting argument or forcing + absoluteness)*. This is a beautiful short application of Tarski's undefinability theorem due to Hjorth, answering [question 10.4](https://people.math.wisc.edu/%7Eawmille1/res/problems.pdf) of A. Miller. Hjorth's [argument](https://people.math.wisc.edu/%7Eawmille1/res/unpub/hjorth-10.4.txt), with minor formatting edits from me, is copied below *(which I've left hidden to avoid spoilers)*:

> Let $X$ be the set of complete theories that satisfy "everything is countable" and have unboundedly many $\alpha<\omega_1^L$ with $L_\alpha$ realising them. The theory of $L_{\omega_1^L}$ is one such theory, and we will be done if we prove that there are some others. Now $X$ is a definable class in $L_{\omega_1^L}$, and so it must have some other elements or else $L_{\omega_1^L}$ would admit a truth definition ($\varphi$ is true in $L_{\omega_1^L}$ iff the unique element of $X$ contains $\varphi$).

Comment: This first result might help me in some way. Do you know a reference for it?

Comment: @Johan Not offhand, but maybe it's an exercise in Kunen or Jech.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look in those.